# помогите с конкатинацией props

Tags: reactjs, map

```
props.loc.title_ +` ${props.cur.} ` + map((key, i) =>
    <a href={props.loc.url_1[i]} target = '_blank'>{key}<br/></a>
)}
```

Помогите пожалуйста правильно прописать , код выше не работает

Comment: `props.loc['title_' + props.cur].map`

Comment: спасибо огромное!)